# CF10 Fieldboost on cfindex has no effect

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-10

Maybe this is a new, mostly unused feature, but I am trying to create a collection based on a query from our DB. It's a simple Q&A and I'd like to rank the matches in the question higher than the answer. Seems logical as currently a search for "register for classes" the question "How do I register for classes" ranks lower than "How to I purchase books for my classes" because content in the books answers I guess matches better. So I'd like to bump the Q&A's if the question matches really well to the text in the query.

CF10 has a "Fieldboost" field on the cfindex however this is having 0 effect on results. I add it and remove it and nothing changes. The score and rank stays the exact same.

```
<cfindex action="refresh" collection="faq" 
      type="custom" 
      title="question" 
      body="question,answer" 
      fieldboost="question:6" 
      key="faq_id" 
      query="updateQuery" 
      location_i="location_id" />
```

`

Comment: As you mentioned, I am not very familiar with this feature.  I'm curious why you have the colon 6 in your attribute `fieldboost="question:6"` though.  Do you have a field named like that?

Comment: Never mind, I found it in some examples.  Looks like a weight.

Comment: Correct. I believe it equates to the Solr question^6 in other documentation. Added weight. It is strange how little documentation/forums topics on this considering how old CF10 is.

Comment: CF10 isn't old - it is the last release. :)

Comment: I know it's not old, but it has been out for a bit. And considering this simple thing isn't working for me out of the box, I would imagine others would be having problems as well.

Comment: Agreed. I'm going to try to recreate this. If you don't hear back from me here, you mind contacting me directly at raymondcamden.com? I can reach out to one of the engineers.

Comment: I'd love to know if you get fieldboost to have any effect on search results.

Answer (score 0):

So I searched Raymond Camden's site and found a little answer that I thought I had tried earlier, but maybe my syntax was wrong. I am using `title:#URL.q#^2` which is working to boost the value of title in the search.

While this works, the CF10 docs indicate I should be able to do this with the `fieldboost` property, which I still cannot get to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) any field that is to be boosted must have `omitNorms="false"` in schema.xml. The default is `false` but is it possible it is being set to `true` in your schema.xml? The other issue I see in the above CFINDEX statement is that you're not specifying a field name in your `fieldboost` parameter, but rather a query column. If you want to boost on `title` then perhaps you need

```
<cfindex ... fieldboost="title:6" ... />
```

?